# Jquery Sortable handle only for specific item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I was wondering if we could define handles for jquery sortable only for specific items.

I have editable and non-editable div's, so I want the editable div's to be sorted only by their handles, and non-editable divs can be dragged without handles.

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items?

Comment: no, i want all the items to be sortable, i want the textboxes(editable divs) to have  a seperate handle(attached to it) to sort them, so that  when the user clicks on it, it will allow typing instead of sorting

Answer (score 2):

if i understand correctly, you want all of them to be sortable, the non-editable with the whole div, and the editable only with its handle.

you have a class .handle?

on the editable, make it a small span or something, on the non-editable make it the whole container div.

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="handle">handle</span>
    <textarea>editable</textarea>
  </li>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <div class="handle">Item 2</div>
 </li>
```

like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jr8xU/

Comment: interesting ... will try this and let u knw

Comment: i tried this, but couldnt figure out how the same design could behave differently in different scenarios. I am not that deep into CSS you see.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery sortable let's you declare handle option dynamically, by using setter like:

```
// setter
$( ".sortable" ).sortable( "option", "handle", ".handle" );
```

If you are coding mouse interface, you can try to listen for mouse over/out events. Then disable the handle over the element without handle:

```
$(".sortable").sortable( "option", "handle", false );
```

And change back on mouse out:

```
$(".sortable").sortable( "option", "handle", ".handle" );
```